# How to create simple ROS Android application

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - my goal is to build a very simple Android app that will run on my phone (HTC ONE M8) and will:

1. Connect to a remote ROS master on the same network
2. Publish Int16 messages to two separate topics

Ideally, I'd like to just create a new project in Android Studio and add dependencies to ros android libs from some external maven repository, and then use things like RosActivity and NodeMain in my project. I'd rather not have to build any ros-android or rosjava libs from source myself. Really want to just keep things as simple as possible here.

Is it possible to do this? I can't find any simple instructions on how to do the above anywhere on wiki.ros.org, and have failed miserably trying to follow the various android setup/build instructions that are on wiki.ros.org.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Zach

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173684/how-to-create-simple-ros-android-application/) by [zcox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18031/zcox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon) is what you're looking for. There is some tutorial on them to understand.

Especially [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_app_manager/Tutorials/hydro/Pairing%20with%20Androids) it talks about pairing with Android. I did not work on that so I can't really tell how cool it is, not how easy or complicated it is though. But I've download the application to try once (Robocon on google play) and it seems quite intuitive.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zcox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18031/zcox/) on 2014-06-16**:
The links you provided eventually led me to this Android Studio Development Environment tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment which I must have somehow overlooked before. That was exactly the setup I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [Android](http://wiki.ros.org/android) package of ROS. Here is the [install instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment)

You can use the Android Studio to design your application but I have to say you need the ros-android and rosjava libs for that.

Also there are some sample applications, which you can use as a template.

For my experience, I can publish my IMU data and video stream from my mobile to the rosmaster.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_xHyifEzRc

---

Originally posted by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) with karma: 279 on 2014-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2